# Laravel whereHas check last latest record for condition in nested relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I need to check if the latest last record in `whereHas` has `type` equal 1.

```
$model->users()
    ->whereHas('relation', function ($query) use ($dates) {
        $query->whereBetween('created_at', $dates)
              ->latest()
              -> .... 
    });
```

EDITED

Answer (score 1):

If by *the latest* you mean the one whose `updated_at` timestamp is the most recent, then you could do something like

```php
->whereHas('relation', function ($query) {
   $query->latest() // orderByDesc('updated_at')
         ->limit(1)
         ->where('type', 1);
})
```

Comment: Ok so I should probably add that it is like second-level relationship, cause I get this error: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause". I'm doing sth like this: $department->users()->whereHas('applications', {....}) and users() is belongsToMany and applications is hasMany

Comment: Are you using any aggregate functions like count(), min(), max() in your query?

Comment: whole query: $department->users()
            ->whereHas('applications', function ($query) use ($dates) {
                $query->whereBetween('created_at', $dates)
                    ->latest()
                    ->limit(1)
                    ->where('type', 1);
            }, '>=', 2)
            ->with([
                'applications' => function ($query) use ($dates) {
                    return $query->whereBetween('created_at', $dates);
                }
            ])
            ->get();